# Uno Platform Native look on feel on iOS and macOS

Tags: uno-platform

Currently, when I build my Uno application, it has the same Windows UWP look and feel. Since Uno should use the underlying platform (thru Xamarin as I understand), how can I have the iOS or macOS default look and feel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Uno Platform renders its control using the native rendering capabilities of the platform, but using the UWP/WinUI visual styles. For some of the basic controls, Uno provides native styles on Android and iOS (see [docs](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/master/doc/articles/native-styles.md)) but it is not available for macOS yet. However, if you are looking for a iOS/macOS look and feel, please keep your eyes on for the next release of Uno Platform (3.6), there might be something that will interest you